# Wordpress Gutenberg Anchor Support for Dynamic Block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to have anchor support for my dynamic wordpress block. I did

```
//in registerBlockType
supports: {
    anchor: true,
},
```

This adds the HTML Anchor control under the sidebar panel.

My block is a dynamic block that has

```
save: ( props ) => {
  return <InnerBlocks.Content />;
}
```

I tried everything to get the `anchor` attribute to to frontend. According to [this github issue](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/6356#issuecomment-419170257) I should add

```
anchor: { 
    type: 'string', 
    source: 'attribute', 
    attribute: 'id', 
    selector: '*', 
},
```

to the blocks attributes. This will make the `anchor` available in the `save` function via `props.anchor`, however it never appears in my `render_callback` `$attributes`.

This is basically a port of the github issue to SO. Hope anyone can help here.

Answer (score 5):

if anyone is still interested this worked for me:

so this is my custom block registering, this statement will enable standard wordpress HTML anchor field (with valuable validation for spaces etc.) under Advanced tab of selected gutenberg block:

```
supports: {
  anchor: true
}
```

then in the same place we define:

```
attributes: {
  anchor: {
    type: 'string'
  }
}
```

then in save function (I have it exactly for the same purpose of `InnerBlocks`):

```
save: function(props) {
  const { anchor } = props.attributes;
  return (
    el( anchor, {}),
    el( InnerBlocks.Content, {})
  );
}
```

if you are using `jsx`, the save function could look like this:

```
save: function(props) {
  const { anchor } = props.attributes;
  return (
    <div id={anchor}>
      <InnerBlocks.Content />
    </div>
  );
}
```

then in your render callback function (in php) it's going to be available via first arg's (which is array) element

```
function your_callback( $block, $content ) {
  // display your anchor value
  echo $block['anchor'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use this filter (targeting whatever blocks you want)

```
const withAnchor = props => {
  if (props.attributes) { // Some blocks don't have attributes
    props.attributes = {
      ...props.attributes,
      anchor: {
        type: 'string'
      }
    }
  }
  return props
}

wp.hooks.addFilter(
  'blocks.registerBlockType',
  'namespace/with-anchor',
  withAnchor
)
```

And then you can access the 'anchor' attribute in the render callback

```
'render_callback' => function($attributes) {
  echo $attributes['anchor'];
}
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. My block's save function returns null and I render block via render_callback function in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried manually adding a field that will take care of the ID attribute?

Something like this:

```
<InspectorControls>
    <PanelBody title={ __( 'Element Settings' ) }>
        <TextControl
            label={ __( 'Element ID', 'fleximpleblocks' ) }
            value={ elementID}
            placeholder={ __( 'Type in the element ID…' ) }
            onChange={ ( value ) => setAttributes( { elementID: value } ) }
        />
    </PanelBody>
</InspectorControls>
```

And then:

```
save: ( props ) => {
    return <InnerBlocks.Content id={ props.attributes.elementID } />;
}
```

I'm not sure if it'll work, I'm just taking a wild guess here. Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: well. of course I can add a custom attribute with another name and make it appear in the `id` attribute of the block. But the question is more about. How can I use the existing field. Maybe gutenberg has to be extended, or maybe I have to use it correctly.

Comment: @niklas for what I've read (specially in the GitHub issue you attached), it's something that hasn't been fully resolved. But even if it was, I would still choose to use the method I suggested above. If you manage to make it work using the `support` property, the anchor field will be “hidden” inside the Advanced tab at the bottom of the `Inspector Controls`. While if you use a custom attribute, you could even display it inside your first settings panel giving a top priority to it.

Comment: Its not hidden. It displays in my `<InspectorControls>` under the advanced panel and makes its way to the save function. Yet it does not appear in the `$attributes` in php as I stated above :(

Comment: @niklas I wrote “hidden”, not hidden. I was implying that there's no quick access to it, and (depending on the amount of panels) it might not be visible at first glance without scrolling down. Something to consider if you'd rather give more visual priority to that attribute ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on answers above.

You just need create an attribute which collects all other attributes/variables/whatever into string.

Step 1

Create an attribute with string type(in block.json)

```json
"phpRender": {
    "type": "string"
}
```

Step 2

In the "edit" function of the block, create a function to save whatever you need to the attribute above. Put this function in "useEffect" hook.

```js
const saveAllToString = () => {
    const blockProps = {
        id: attributes.anchor,
    }

    setAttributes({phpRender: JSON.stringify(blockProps)});
}

useEffect(() => {
    saveAllToString();
});
```

Step 3

Now you can decode this string and use variables easily.

```php
$blockProps = !empty($attributes['phpRender']) ? json_decode($attributes['phpRender']) : false;
echo $blockProps->id;
```